# How to show pricing attributes in View

Tags: commerce

I'm using [Pricing Attributes module](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_pricing_attributes), but i don't know how to show its in line item view, in shopping cart view and in shopping cart form view.

How do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the following view: Shopping cart form (Commerce Order).
And add a the field: Commerce Line Item: Product Attributes, this will show the product with the extra attributes.